# Change WooCommerce Checkout Page Drop Down Field Items Text Color

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors

[image]

As you see, my main website font color is white. Now in the WooCommerce Checkout Page all drop down fields' items are also white in color, thus users can't check the drop down items without hovering over them.

I guess I'm expecting some additional CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

```html
.select2-container--open {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Did the Trick!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).